# .Net Core apps on Mono

Tags: pi-zero-w, mono

Trying to run .Net Core app with Mono on Raspberry Pi Zero W (as you know, .Net Core JIT is not support the ARMv6 processor instructions) and I've got error all time:

> Cannot open assembly '#assembly_name#': File does not contain a valid
>   CIL image.

[Looks like Mono isn't support .Net Core](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).
So, is there any way to run .Net Core apps on Raspberry Pi Zero (maybe without Mono with something else)?

Comment: You may have to spend the extra $30 and buy a full sized Pi. I know that will run Windows IoT and will handle Mono stuff just fine. Remember, the versions of Linux that are on the Pi are reduced instruction set versions. If you need the small format of the Zero, I'd suggest writing your code in Python, Java or C(/C++).

Answer (score 1):

You can't run .Net core apps on a arm32v6 cpu at the moment.
But if you rewrite your app in normal .net then you can use mono to run it on your pi zero

Comment: Yep I know that I can rewrite my app. And yep I know that I can't run .Net Core apps for now. I'm just waiting for the solution

Comment: Currently I don't think there is any other solution.